# link shown as file, different on various html pages, different by browser

Tags: html, angularjs, firefox, microsoft-edge

I made a small "project" using AngularJS. I created a directive to transform some string patterns in links. I use the javascript file in some html files. One of the patterns I want to "linkify" is "//www.google.com". I open the html files with Firefox or Edge. The indicated link looks different in each situation. When I inspect the element, I see in each situation:

```
<a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">//www.google.com</a>
```

But when I hoover the mouse in browser over the link, I see in the lower left corner of the browser:

- in case of one html page in Firefox:        www.google.com
- in case of another html page in Firefox:    file:///
- in Edge, both pages:                file://www.google.com/

Of course, when I try to open the link by clicking on it in browser, I am taken to the same "address" which I see when I hoover the mouse over the link. What I need is the variant:

www.google.com

I don't actually care in this stage of the project whether is a correct or valid web address.

Why this different behavior?

Comment: No idea why you get inconsistent behaviour for the 2 cases in Firefox, but I suspect it all has to do with the double slash at front ... I believe what happens is that the first slash is interpreted as a relative path and all goes wrong from there ...

Comment: To be on the safe side, you should probably fully specify the protocol e.g. `https://www.google.com`. See docs of href syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)